# Method to change class variable in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I'm trying to change class variable with a method:

```
class Test():

    someVar = 0

    def __init__(self, val1):
        self.val1 = val1

    def changeVar(self):
        Test.someVar = self.val1**2

val = 2
var1 = Test(val)

print(var1.someVar)
```

However, I get the "0" as the output. Somehow I have an error in reasoning.

Comment: You're missing a `self.`…

Comment: `self.someVar = self.val1**2`

Comment: @Bear Brown, I still get the "0".

Comment: @ingenium add to the question how do you initial an instance an print value

Comment: You're never calling `changeVar`…

Comment: @deceze make sense ...

Comment: Please call it and see the o/p, it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Test:

  someVar = 0

  def __init__(self, val1):
    self.someVar = val1 * 2     

val = 2

var1 = Test(val)     

print(var1.someVar)
```

or

```
class Test:

  someVar = 0

  def __init__(self, val1):
    self.someVar = val1
    self.changeVar()

  def changeVar(self):
    self.someVar = self.someVar * 2


val = 2

var1 = Test(val)     

print(var1.someVar)
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer it as `Test.somevar`

```
def changeVar(self):
    Test.someVar = self.val1**2
```

Optionally you can refer it as `self.__class__.x` or even shortly as `self.somevar` (when you dont have any other object var under the same name)

Comment: `Test.` vs. `self.__class__.` vs. `self.` really depends on the intent of *which* property you want to change. It's not all equal.

Comment: Ofcourse... But I was answering for the scope of this particular question